# How can one apply font weights to custom styles which are set as a `textAppearance` in XML on a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I'm talking about fonts that come as "Thin", "Regular", "Medium", "Semibold". Not the bold/italic text style.
Note: I am looking for a way to apply font weight in a reusable style via XML. Applying the font weight can be done programmatically (as noted in this Google Issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145311058) but this is not ideal when you have hundreds of TextViews in layout resources.

For instance, I have a font set at my app theme level:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
   <item name="fontFamily">@font/rubik</item>
   <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/rubik</item>
   ...
</style>

<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <font
    android:font="@font/rubik_regular"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="300"
    app:font="@font/rubik_regular"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="300" />
  <font
    android:font="@font/rubik_italic"
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="300"
    app:font="@font/rubik_italic"
    app:fontStyle="italic"
    app:fontWeight="300" />
  <font
    android:font="@font/rubik_medium"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="500"
    app:font="@font/rubik_medium"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="500" />
  <font
    android:font="@font/rubik_medium_italic"
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="500"
    app:font="@font/rubik_medium_italic"
    app:fontStyle="italic"
    app:fontWeight="500" />
</font-family>
```

And then I have custom styles that I apply to the `textAppearance` attribute on my TextViews:

```
<style name="SmallTextOnBackgroundMediumWeightTextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/themeColorTextOnBackground</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/rubik</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/rubik</item>
    <item name="android:textFontWeight">500</item>
</style>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/SmallTextOnBackgroundMediumWeightTextView" />
```

Note: In this example, setting the `<item name="android:textFontWeight">500</item>` in my custom style does not apply the medium weight font to my TextView.

I have tried explicitly setting the `android:fontFamily` and `fontFamily` items in my style to the specific medium font `@font/rubik_medium`. And this does NOT work.

The only thing that seems to work is explicitly setting `android:textStyle="bold"` on the TextView directly, which doesn't feel right and doesn't solve the issue if you have multiple "bolder" weights. Or you can set `android:textFontWeight="500"` on the TextView directly, which defeats the purpose of having reusable custom styles for TextViews, since you'll be applying your custom style + an extra `textFontWeight` on every.. single.. TextView.

Can someone help me out here? How can I reuse my custom styles and also set a font weight in them?

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
<style name="SmallTextOnBackgroundMediumWeightTextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/themeColorTextOnBackground</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/rubik</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/rubik</item>
    <item name="android:textFontWeight">500</item>
    <item name="android:fontWeight">500</item>
    <item name="fontWeight">500</item>
</style>
```

after im test 
android:textFontWeight is requires api level 28 and 
android:fontWeight is requeres api level 26
hope this help